# Does the pipeline object in sklearn transform the test data when using the .predict() method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When I use a pipeline object,

1. Does the pipeline object fit **and transform** the train data when I use the `.fit()` method? Or should I use the `.fit_transform()` method? What is the difference between the two?
2. When I use the `.predict()` method on the test data, does the pipeline object **transform the test data and only then predict it?** That is, should I  transform the test data using the `.transform()` method before I use the `.predict()` method?

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier



#creating some data
X, y = np.ones((50, 1)), np.hstack(([0] * 45, [1] * 5))

#creating the pipeline
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('SelectKBest', SelectKBest(f_classif, k=3)), ('pca', PCA(n_components=2)), ('DT', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0))]
model = Pipeline(steps=steps)

#splitting the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Pipeline object is exposing the methods of its last step. As your last step is a `DecisionTreeClassifier` (an Estimator), the pipeline will not have a `fit_transform()` but estimator functions such as `fit()`, `predict()`, `score()` etc.

When using `fit()`, the pipeline will call `fit_transform()` on all transformer and finally a `fit()` on the estimator.

When using `predict()` the pipeline will `transform()` all the data and then call `predict()` on the estimator.

As depicted in this picture: (Image from Raschka, Sebastian. Python machine learning. Birmingham, UK: Packt Publishing, 2015. Print)

[image]

Comment: Any source for the (nice) image?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer with the source.

Comment: Brilliantly useful diagram, thank you!

Comment: What about when doing cross-validation? will the validation fold get fit_transformed or only transformed?

Comment: Wow! This is so well-explained! Thank you so much.